# Does Python import copy all the code into the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, sys.path

When we import a module in a Python script, does this copy all the required code into the script, or does it just let the script know where to find it?

What happens if we don't use the module then in the code, does it get optimized out somehow, like in C/C++?

Comment: The script is compiled to bytecode and then interpreted. But this is an implementation detail and different Python interpreters are free to do what they want.

Comment: No, it creates a module object from the source code.

Answer (score 2):

None of those things are the case.

An import does two things. First, if the requested module has not previously been loaded, the import *loads* the module. This mostly boils down to creating a new global scope and executing the module's code in that scope to initialize the module. The new global scope is used as the module's attributes, as well as for global variable lookup for any code in the module.

Second, the import binds whatever names were requested. `import whatever` binds the `whatever` name to the `whatever` module object. `import whatever.thing` also binds the `whatever` name to the `whatever` module object. `from whatever import somefunc` looks up the `somefunc` attribute on the `whatever` module object and binds the `somefunc` name to whatever the attribute lookup finds.

Unused imports cannot be optimized out, because both the module loading and the name binding have effects that some other code might be relying on.

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? Is the code copied into the current script / module when loaded?

Comment: I'm wondering mainly just for interest, because if we keep loading modules does this cause the script to get bigger and bigger, or is the imported code linked in a different way?

Comment: No. Importing is not `#include`. It doesn't dump another file into yours. I explained the basics of module loading in the answer: the module's code is executed in a new scope. As I also explained in the answer, this only happens once, not on every import.